# Shift Paging To Next Page On submit Click

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, pagination

Below Mention is the paging i have done using MVC PageList on my partial view and also i have one submit button on my partial view

Controller

```
var model1 = PrepareTestModel((int)_studAnsdal.Test_Id, Page);
            ViewBag.TestId = TestId;
            Page++;
           return PartialView("_studentPartial", model1.OrderByDescending(v => v.Question_Id).ToPagedList(Page, 1));
```

View

```
 <input type="submit"  Value="Submit Answer" id="abc">     

    <div class="pagedList">
           @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("TestPaging", "Student", new { page=ViewBag.page, TestId = ViewBag.TestId }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results", HttpMethod = "POST" }))

         </div>
```

What i want to do is whenver user click on submit i want to shift my paging value to the next page that is one increment to it but i m not getting it done as page value is passed using query string any help is appreciated

Comment: where you are setting 'page=ViewBag.page' just do as 'page=(((int)ViewBag.page)+1)'

Comment: it says Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nullable value type

Comment: then be sure there is int value inside viewbag..

Comment: u r not gettin me each time my submit button is press and post method is called the page value sets to 1 by default i want to overcome this

Comment: i just want to incremet page value which is passed as query string in pagelist pager if i get it in hidden field i can do it do u have any idea how can i get that page query string value in hidden field

Comment: just set current page no in ViewBag.page and then do as i have told in first comment

Comment: but what if user navigates to previous page